# I have main but java command not working

Tags: java, swing

I know Java need main function and I have one. This code compile with no error (This code is source code of the Design Pattern book) ,but when I execute

```
D:\ java SwingObserverExample 
Error: Could not find or load main class SwingObserverExample
```

here is source code:

```
package headfirst.designpatterns.observer.swing;

import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class SwingObserverExample{
    JFrame frame;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingObserverExample example = new SwingObserverExample();
    example.go();
}

public void go() {
    frame = new JFrame();

    JButton button = new JButton("Should I do it?");

    // Without lambdas
    //button.addActionListener(new AngelListener());
    //button.addActionListener(new DevilListener());

    // With lambdas
    button.addActionListener(event -> 
        System.out.println("Don't do it, you might regret it!")
    );
    button.addActionListener(event ->
        System.out.println("Come on, do it!")
    );
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);

    // Set frame properties 
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, button);
    frame.setSize(300,300);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

/*
 * Remove these two inner classes to use lambda expressions instead.
 * 
class AngelListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Don't do it, you might regret it!");
    }
}

class DevilListener implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
        System.out.println("Come on, do it!");
    }
}
*/
```

why java can't find this program's main class ?

directory of my java file is `D:\workplace\Head-First-Design-Patterns-master\Head-First-Design-Patterns-master\src\headfirst\designpatterns\observer\swing`
and I run java command from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the package name in the run command

```
java headfirst.designpatterns.observer.swing.SwingObserverExample
```

Also Java expects to find the class in a directory `headfirst\designpatterns\observer\swing` relative to the current location to match the package name so run the application from

```
D:\workplace\Head-First-Design-Patterns-master\Head-First-Design-Patterns-maste‌​‌​r\src
```

Comment: You havent said what your directory structure is like but Java expects the class to be in a directory `headfirst\designpatterns\observer\swing` relative to the current location....

Comment: my directory is `D:\workplace\Head-First-Design-Patterns-master\Head-First-Design-Patterns-master\src\headfirst\designpatterns\observer\swing`

Comment: In that case you can use a runtime location of `D:\workplace\Head-First-Design-Patterns-master\Head-First-Design-Patterns-maste‌​r\src`

Comment: It's worked. please include this in your answer and I will mark your answer as solution. It's better to include link about java package tutorial. Thanks again

Comment: I have irrelevant question (about you), I beg leave to say in this comment ?

Answer (score 1):

This is because of the line `package headfirst.designpatterns.observer.swing`.
The class is compiled in the package `headfirst.designpatterns.observer.swing`.

Either remove that or (better) run it using

```
java headfirst.designpatterns.observer.swing.SwingObserverExample
```

Comment: I removed firs line and it worked, why this is happened?

Comment: @saman, beacuse now it is in default package. And that's why you don't have to mention the package information. I think Reimeus solution also works fine in this case

Comment: @Razib where can I find some information about this or what keyword I must search?

Comment: @saman, Search for [java packages](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/package/packages.html).

Answer (score 0):

While executing the code using `java` command use classpath - `cp` option and add the fully qualified class name where the main method exist -

```
java -cp headfirst.designpatterns.observer.swing.SwingObserverExample
```